# Scraping without specific strings in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape only emoji in Python3. I used starttwith method with if statement but the result got some Unicodes that emoji's HTML tag seems to be same as others. I have no idea why some emoji is converted into Unicode. Could you give me any advice ?? or there is any ways to remove this unicode from list.
[image]

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

list0 = []

site_url = "https://www.emojiall.com/zh-hant/categories/A"
get_url = requests.get(site_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_url.text, "lxml")

for script in soup(["span"]):
    script.extract()
    
emojis = soup.select('.emoji_font')
words = soup.select('.emoji_name_truncate')

for emoji0 in emojis:
    emoji1 = emoji0.getText()
    if not repr(emoji1).startswith(r'\U'):
        list0.append(emoji1)
    else:
        continue
print(list0)
```

Comment: Some emojis are not present in Windows. So depending on your use case you shouldn't skip these. Also all emojis/unicodes  start with \U.

Comment: thank you for your comment . this problem was caused by my editor .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated editor and it works well .

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

list0 = []

site_url = "https://www.emojiall.com/zh-hant/categories/A"
get_url = requests.get(site_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_url.text, "lxml")

for script in soup(["span"]):
    script.extract()

emojis = soup.select('.emoji_font')
words = soup.select('.emoji_name_truncate')

for emoji0 in emojis:
    emoji1 = emoji0.getText()
    if not repr(emoji1).startswith(r"'\U"):
        list0.append(emoji1)
    else:
        continue
print(list0)
```